# Can't filter Chroma VectorDB answers based on directory path.... I have multiple PDFs saved in specific directory and want answers from those

Tags: filtering, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I have 3 folders in Data folder of project.
In every folder I have several PDFs.
User will have option to select one or many folders out of them.
Based on selected folders answer should come from LLM.

```
# Get the list of directory paths from the user
directory_paths = input("Enter the directory paths (separated by spaces): ").split()

# Create a list to store the target directories
target_directories = []

# Iterate through the list of directory paths and add them to the target_directories list
for directory_path in directory_paths:
    target_directory = os.path.join("....\\gpt_proj\\data\\", directory_path)
    target_directories.append(target_directory)
print(target_directories)



vectordb_retri = vectordb.as_retriever(search_type = "similarity", search_kwargs={"k": 2, "include_metadata": True, "filter":{"source":target_directories } })



qa_for_anwering = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=model,
    condense_question_prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vectordb_retri,
    get_chat_history=lambda c:c,
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": qa_prompt},
    return_source_documents=True,
    memory=memory,
    return_generated_question=True,
    verbose=True,
)

query = "When was USAID Regional Development Mission Asia was established and what was its purpose?"
result = qa_for_anwering(query)
process_llm_output(result,query)
```

Now this is not working getting error or LLM is able to access other folders and answer the quetion, Please help